# curl error 28 while downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json: Connection timed out after 10006 milliseconds

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to create a symfony skeleton project using below command

> composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_name

After, I hit the enter, its starts installing symfony and after few seconds it shows below error

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while
> downloading
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json:
> Connection timed out after 10006 milliseconds

I want to create a symfony project using composer only, is there a way?

I also created an issue with symfony git repository, they shifted the issue to discussions (below is the url)

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/48733#discussioncomment-4512675

Composer Version : 2.1.12

Php Version I have tried : 8.0.2 and 8.1

Comment: can you provide more information like, version of php, version of composer

Comment: @RicardoJesusRuiz, I am using composer version  2.1.12 and Php version 8.0.2 (I have also treid php 8.1)

Comment: Why not use any more current version? That version of Composer is more than a year old, and PHP 8.0.2 is even nearly two years old

Comment: @NicoHaase, I also tried with composer  2.5.1 and php 8.1 . It returns the same error.

Comment: Sounds like you are facing a network issue. Can you load the given URL in a browser? Do you use any kind of VPN?

Comment: No, I can not load the url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json  in my browser. I am not using any VPN

Comment: Maybe your provider is blocking that url, from my side, I see the url perfect, can you try to add this ip to your DNS 8.8.8.8

Comment: If you cannot even open that URL in a browser, you need to check your system for problems. This is in no way a programming-related problem then

Comment: @RicardoJesusRuiz ,I think you are correct. issue seems to be related to my network. Let me try what you are is suggesting

Comment: @RicardoJesusRuiz, I added 8.8.8.8 in hosts file but, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I also tried opening this with other laptop, But it didn't open. May be, I need to check my ISP.

Comment: @RicardoJesusRuiz, You are correct. My ISP was blocking that url. I tried with some other ISP and it worked.  You can write an Answer, It may be helpful to others.